# How does the XOR operator function in this program?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bitwise-operators

I found one solution the Sock Merchant HackerRank problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sock-merchant), which is the following:

```
using namespace std;


int main(){


   int n;
cin>>n;
int i;
int arr[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];
sort(arr,arr+n);
int c=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{

    if((arr[i]^arr[i+1])==0)
    {
        c++;
        i++;
    }

}
cout<<c<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

I don't really understand what is happenning in the if statement. I read somewhere that ^ is an `XOR` symbol, but I don't understand how it functions in this program....

Comment: What about reading a book about C or C++?

Comment: [List of C++ operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: @samgak You are right, I edited the title of the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise XOR (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR)

> arr[i]^arr[i+1]

check if `arr[i]` and `arr[i+1]` are different (return 1 if they are different, 0 otherwise). More precisely, `(arr[i]^arr[i+1])` is a boolean expression, so it returns `true` if both numbers are different, and `false` otherwise.

Comment: `return 1 if they are different` More like not-0, but not necessarily 1. It's not a boolean logic operator

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `^` is the `xor` operator : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/xor / https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Comment: Ok, but what does it do in this program?

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are the same, bitwise XOR works as follows, e.g.:

```
1011 0110
1011 0110
---- ----
0000 0000
```

If the numbers are different (even in only 1 bit) then e.g.:

```
1011 1110
1011 0110
---- ----
0000 1000
```

So basically:

```
if((arr[i]^arr[i+1])==0)
//is the same as
if (arr[i] == arr[i+1])
```

Hooray for readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise `XOR`operation is used to check if variable 1 and variable 2 is different. In your example's case, whether `arr[i]` and `arr[i+1]` is same or different.

```
same ^ same = false
same ^ different = true
different ^ same = true
different ^ different = false
```

The simplest explanation i can come up with. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise Xor concept is

xor of same values will be 0 and

xor of different value will be 1

You have not checked the array index
here

```
if((arr[i]^arr[i+1])==0)
    {
        c++;
        i++;
    }
```

arr[i+1] is excedding the maximum limit for index.

Final code

```
int main(){
int n;
cin>>n;
int i;
int arr[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];
sort(arr,arr+n);
int c=0;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{

    if((arr[i]^arr[i-1])==0)
    {
        c++;
        i++;
    }

}
cout<<c<<endl;
return 0;

}
```